# How do you configure views block based on node reference in Drupal 8/9?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-blocks, drupal-content-types

There is a node **pages** that holds reference fields of the taxonomies (course type and semester). For example:

- Summer Literature Courses: **course type** of 'Literature' and a **semester** of 'Summer'.

There is a node **courses** that holds reference fields of the taxonomies. For example:

- ENG 101: **course type** of 'Literature' and a **semester** of 'Summer'.
- MTH 101: **course type** of 'Math' and a **semester** of 'Fall'.

I need to somehow get those courses on the **page** that both reference the same **course type** and **semester**

I figured I could create a views block and place that on all pages that have **course type** and **semester** defined. But I can't figure out how to configure the View to correctly filter the courses. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

- Create a block view that displays courses (content type filter).
- Create 2 "contextual filters", 1 for **course type** and 1 for **semester**.
- In the above contextual filters, set them both to "When filter is not available" to "Provide default value" -> "Content ID from URL".
- add the block to the page.

Both the "page" and "course" content type must be using the same fields for referencing the **course type** and **semester**.

On the view settings page (admin/structure/views/settings) there is a setting for "Show the SQL query" which is helpful to see the SQL query on the preview